# fire data driven subscription by schedule from sql

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subscriptions

Is there a way to fire data driven subscription by schedule  from sql server management studio?
 I've found a way to fire subscription on demand, but it runs immediately, I'm just looking for a way to pass the firing date to my subscription like a parameter.

```
SELECT @JobID = S.[SubscriptionID]
    FROM Reports.[dbo].[Subscriptions] S
    INNER JOIN Reports.[dbo].[Catalog] C ON S.[Report_OID] = C.[ItemID]
    WHERE C.[Name] + '_' + S.[Description] = @name

exec Reports.[dbo].[AddEvent] @EventType, @JobID;
```

where @name is subscription name

Comment: A Reporting Services subscription? The term subscription also refers to replication, you should better tag properly your question.

Comment: Yes it's  Reporting Services subscription.Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of @EventType? `TimedSubscription`?

Comment: yes it's `'TimedSubscription'`

Comment: So you need to modify the schedule of an existing Subscription and then launch it manually?

Comment: Yes . I want to lunch it manually, but I also want to say the subscription to be fired let's say in two ours.

Comment: I've found a way to change the schedule via reporting service web interface , but I'm looking for a way to do that via sql .